# how can I install section 0p of man pages?

Tags: linux, terminal, operating-system, debian, manpage

On my pc with debian 11 installed, I only have sections 1 to 9 of the manual. However on the online linux manual there's also a section 0p containing the C header files, in which I am interested: is it possible to install section 0p locally?

The wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) says "On some systems some of the following sections are available:", including section 0, but I wonder what it means by "on some systems", if it means that you don't have them by default or that you can't even install them later.

Comment: Man pages are just the electronic version of what we had nearly every computer: a book (or several ones). Every manufacturer had own layouts. `Section 0` is often the introduction or or other generic parts (which doesn't fit on other sections). How do you organize each section is somewhat arbitrary (but inspired on original section numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'p' in there refers to POSIX.  On Debian and other Debian-based distros such as Ubuntu, the POSIX header man pages are provided by the [manpages-posix-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stable/manpages-posix-dev) package (and they are in section 7).